# Can cuda be used combining with activeX technology?

Tags: c++, activex, cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

every one. i am a newbie to cuda. i am wondering that can cuda be used combining with ActiveX technology，
the presented ocx or dll file can be used in webpage，
for example， using cuda can we simulate a fluid particle easily.
if combine cuda and activeX technology ,
we can see fluid particle in a webpage, am i right?
what's more, if there are problems when i simulate lots of particles?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if ActiveX could access your GPU on such low level as running your arbitrary CUDA code, it would be a big security risk. If on the other hand, ActiveX could perform some of its computations on the GPU though some higher-level interface, that would be safer, but it is Microsoft who would have to implement it, not you.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it will be a big security risk,but activex file with digital signature can run on IE or other web browser unblockedly, actually i want to show better effect on my webpage, but it will cost in computation, so i am thinking if i can combining activex and cuda as a solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are right, it will be a big security risk, maybe activex file with digital signature can run on IE or other web browser unblockedly. Actually i want to show better effect on my webpage, like particals, water, smoke, tree and so on. But they are cost in computation, so i am thinking whether can i treat combining activex and cuda as a solution. if you have other idears to tell me, i will  Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: "if you have other idears to tell me" - I am afraid I don't. I know almost nothing about ActiveX. I work with CUDA. But a bug in CUDA can lead to complete system hang and/or your monitor to freeze - hence my imminent concerns.

Comment: "a bug in CUDA can lead to complete system hang and/or your monitor to freeze" - what kind of bug do you mean? can you explain it in details? more thanks to you.

Comment: I mean a bug in your CUDA source. GPU operates in real-mode, memory is not really protected and you can (accidently or not) write over some sensitive data. Sometimes Windows cannot recover from those problems. Win7 usually just resets the GPU, but XP can completely hang.

Answer (score 1):

A trusted ActiveX control can do *anything*. So, yes, you could theoretically spin up the CUDA runtime and go to town with the GPU. You would need to distribute the CUDA runtime with the ActiveX control, but everything else you need would already be installed assuming they're using an nVidia GPU. FWIW, distributing cudart.dll *is* permissable per the EULA on the CUDA Developer Toolkit.

Since, [last I read](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=77104), you cannot statically link against cudart.dll, you would need to distribute that dependency along with your ActiveX control by using a CAB file. [Details on creating CAB files can be found here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974%28VS.85%29.aspx#Cabinet_Files). Then again that forum post is from 2008, so maybe newer versions of cudart.dll can be statically linked now... you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, what's more, what did you mean "You would need to distribute the CUDA runtime with the ActiveX control," can you explain it in details ?

Comment: The cudart.dll doesn't exist on the user's machine, so you would need to package it up with the ActiveX control in order to get that dependency to the user's machine. You would need to look into distributing your ActiveX control in a CAB file to accomplish this since, last I heard, you cannot statically link cudart.dll. I will add more details about packaging to the answer.

Comment: yes, you are right, and i know activeX use CAB file to excute, and i know how to package DLL or ocx type file into CAB file too, but i don't know you metioned in "cannot statically link against cudart.dll" means what. Or you mean i should package cudart.dll and my activex control file into CAB file for web browser's downloading. Then on PC there will be both my activex control file and cucart.dll file. Then i can run cuda program successfully? am i right?

Comment: As long as the user has an nvidia GPU that supports CUDA along with recent drivers, yes, that should be all. If you could statically link to cudart.dll you'd only have to worry about distributing you're own DLL.

Comment: How about an upvote (if not marking this as the answer) if this information has been useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, it runs on the client machine. What means that the client needs to have a CUDA enabled graphics card (nVidia only).

Comment: So it means that if i have a nvidia card, using activex technology can get same performance as it is does in local? Thank you for you reply

Comment: can you expain it in details? Thanks .

Comment: any idears are wellcome, Thanks a lot.